# DOORS DXL Show output during run

Tags: ibm-doors

While my DXL script is running on a module I have it `print "."` during each loop.

I would like this to show in the output while it running, to reassure the user it isn't frozen since it takes a long time to run.

Currently the DXL windows is blocked from the moment the script starts, and when the script is completely done it prints everything at once.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a GUI, a progress bar or write something to a file.
you could use timer callbacks to update your screen.